# Version of GCC required to build cmake 3.X.Y

Tags: gcc, cmake

I'm trying to compile cmake version 3.0.2 on GCC 4.9.2 but I'm getting the error message

```
/home/DrNo/cmake-3.0.2/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /home/DrNo/cmake-3.0.2/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake)
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Problem while running initial CMake
```

I've taken a look at the ABI strings(?) in `libstdc++.so.6` and can't find `GLIBCXX_3.4.15`:

```
$ strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

I've tried cmake compiling versions 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2 and 3.7.2 but all require  GLIBCXX_3.4.15, so it looks like I'm going to have to upgrade my version of GCC on this system (CentOS), which I don't want to because I've built this project on another system (Ubuntu with prepackaged cmake 3.0.2) with GCC 4.9.2.

Is it possible to have two GCC installs. A more recent one to build cmake and GCC 4.9.2 to build the rest of the project.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but be aware that CMake provides a binary distribution in form of a shell script containing a self-extracting archive. The version 3.0.2 is [here](https://cmake.org/files/v3.0/cmake-3.0.2-Linux-i386.sh). The script takes a `--prefix=` option allowing to install it anywhere you like. You don't *have* to compile CMake from source. That being said, it looks like your toolchain has some issues, so that installation *might* not work as expected either.

Comment: @DevSolar I was concerned about compatibility with CentOS. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Why would you get such an old version of cmake? Is /home/DrNo/cmake-3.0.2/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake a binary that came with cmake, or that was built during the process? In the last case, the problem is that you already have 2 versions of gcc...

Comment: @DevSolar The Linux binaries worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you managed to get rid of the problem i am just leaving this comment here as a future reference:

I did have a similar problem when compiling cmake version 3.10.0 on `gcc4.1.2` . I looked at my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and saw that there was a path from a former gcc version.

I simply set it to the correct path something along the lines `gcc_4.1.2/linux50_64/lib64` via `setenv`. Nifty trick I learned was using `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}/your/path/here:` which basically appends your path to the everything inside `LD_PATH_LIBRARY` variable.